Nextjs15 next-intl always forcing me to open website with /en prefix if middleware has "en" in locales, but i set defaultLocale "az"
These are my routing.js and middleware.js files. If i add locales array for example "fr" instead of "en" its opening website "az" (default prefix). Btw im using nextjs 15 and next-intl for localization. I neeed just open website default /az (with no prefix)
>! /src/middleware.js
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales: ["az", "en", "ru"],
  defaultLocale: "az",
  localePrefix: "as-needed",
  async getLocale({ cookies, headers }) {
    if (cookies.get("NEXT_LOCALE")) {
      return cookies.get("NEXT_LOCALE");
    }

    const acceptLanguage = headers.get("accept-language");
    if (acceptLanguage) {
      const matchedLocale = ["az", "en", "ru"].find((locale) =>
        acceptLanguage.startsWith(locale)
      );
      if (matchedLocale) return matchedLocale;
    }

    return "az";
  },
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)"],
};

export default intlMiddleware;


>! /app/i18n/routing.js
import { defineRouting } from "next-intl/routing";
import { createNavigation } from "next-intl/navigation";

export const routing = defineRouting({
  locales: ["az", "en", "ru"],
  defaultLocale: "az",
});

export const { Link, redirect, usePathname, useRouter } =
  createNavigation(routing);


I tried adding i18n locales on next.config.mjs but i got error.
